# Can a Windows box authenticate with Samba without username/password?

Tags: authentication, samba

Is there a way to authenticate a machine to Samba without relying on a username/password?

I have a couple of Windows web servers using a third machine hosting Samba for common files. I would like not to relay on a changeble username/password. I would like something like ssh public/private key exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to use the Windows AD domain, samba must be it's member (or even DC, if you will chose this way), so the authentication will happen transparently, using Kerberos tickets.

Unfortunately, comprehensive answer on this question is too long to post it in this short form. But yes, this is achievable.

Comment: Unfortunately I Have a very some architecture with these three machines only (well there's varnish in the game but it is not the point here)

Comment: DC on samba or on a VM then.